# Dynamically Changing Data Type for a Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a set of data frames belonging to many countries consisting of 3 variables (*year*, *AI*, *OAD*). The example for *Zimbabwe* is shown as below,

```
>str(dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year: chr  "1955" "1956" "1957" "1958" ...
 $ AI  : chr  "11.61568161" "11.34114927" "11.23639317" "11.18841409" ...
 $ OAD : chr  "5.740789488" "5.775882473" "5.800441036" "5.822536579" ...
```

I am trying to change the data type of the variables in data frame to below so that I can model the linear fit using `lm(dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970$AI ~ dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970$year)`.

```
>str(dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970) 
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year: int  1955 1956 1957 1958 ...
 $ AI  : num  11.61568161 11.34114927 11.23639317 11.18841409 ...
 $ OAD : num  5.740789488 5.775882473 5.800441036 5.822536579 ...
```

The below static code able to change *AI* from character (*chr*) to numeric (*num*).

```
dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970$AI <- as.numeric(dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970$AI)
```

However when I tried to automate the code as below, *AI* still remains as character (*chr*)

```
countries <- c('Zimbabwe', 'Afghanistan', ...) 

for (country in countries) {
  assign(paste('dframe_',country,'_1955_1970$AI', sep=''), eval(parse(text = paste('as.numeric(dframe_',country,'_1955_1970$AI)', sep=''))))
}
```

Can you advice what I could have done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `assign( ...$var_name, value)` function.

Comment: Each of your data frame seems very small.  Why don't you stack them into a single data frame?  Then you don't need this complex syntax.

Comment: The right hand side of assign() produces values as below,
eval(parse(text = paste('as.numeric(dframe_',country,'_1955_1970$AI)', sep='')))
 [1] 11.615682 11.341149 11.236393 11.188414 11.108672 10.973661 10.807027 10.573861 10.326624 10.131940 10.010619
[12]  9.809184  9.676503  9.592671  9.523880  9.455642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be considered fairly ugly code by teh purists but perhaps this:

```
for (country in countries) {

    new_val <- get(paste('dframe_',country,'_1955_1970', sep=''))
    new_val[] <- lapply(new_val, as.numeric)  # the '[]' on LHS keeps dataframe
    assign(paste('dframe_',country,'_1955_1970', sep=''), new_val)
          }
```

Using the `get('obj_name')` function is considered cleaner than `eval(parse(text=...))`. It would get handled more R-naturally had you assembled these dataframes in a list.

Comment: I have editted line 2 as,
   new_val <- get(paste('dframe_',country,'_1955_1970', sep=''))

The output for that still has AI as chr :
'data.frame': 16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year: chr  "1955" "1956" "1957" "1958" ...
 $ AI  : chr  "11.61568161" "11.34114927" "11.23639317" "11.18841409" ...
 $ OAD : chr  "5.740789488" "5.775882473" "5.800441036" "5.822536579" ...

Strange. I tried get() earlier and got no changes too

Comment: `get` does not do any "changing". Its the `lapply ... , as.numeric)` that applies the change. My point was that you cannot do a column-focussed change with assign.

Comment: Will analyze this further with your leads. Thanks

Comment: Wasn't me.Sorry

Answer (score 2):

42: Your code doesn't work as written but with some edits it will. in addition to the missing parentheses and wrong sep, you can't use $'column name' in assign, but you don't need it anyway

```
for (country in countries) {
  new_val <- get(paste( 'dframe_',country,'_1955_1970', sep=''))
  new_val[] <- lapply(new_val, as.numeric)  # the '[]' on LHS keeps dataframe
  assign(paste('dframe_',country,'_1955_1970', sep=''), new_val)
  remove(new_val)
}
```

proof it works:

```
dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970 <- data.frame(year = c("1955", "1956", "1957"), 
                                         AI = c("11.61568161", "11.34114927", "11.23639317"),
                                         OAD = c("5.740789488", "5.775882473", "5.800441036"),
                                         stringsAsFactors = F)
str(dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year: chr  "1955" "1956" "1957"
 $ AI  : chr  "11.61568161" "11.34114927" "11.23639317"
 $ OAD : chr  "5.740789488" "5.775882473" "5.800441036"

 countries <- 'Zimbabwe'
 for (country in countries) {
 new_val <- get(paste( 'dframe_',country,'_1955_1970', sep=''))
   new_val[] <- lapply(new_val, as.numeric)  # the '[]' on LHS keeps dataframe
   assign(paste('dframe_',country,'_1955_1970', sep=''), new_val)
   remove(new_val)
 }

str(dframe_Zimbabwe_1955_1970)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year: num  1955 1956 1957
 $ AI  : num  11.6 11.3 11.2
 $ OAD : num  5.74 5.78 5.8
```

Comment: Thanks. I have editted 42's code and its currently under peer review. Thanks for your help too, I came about the same answer as you and 42 proposed.